# Create list out of a particular element of sublists

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice, sublist

My title is probably incredibly confusing, so I'll just give an example. For the following list:

```
 x = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
```

So, if you wanted from an index of one, the resultant list would be:

```
 [2,5,8]
```

Is there a short way to do this? Obviously you can iterate through the outside list and simply grab each element of index 1, but is there any easy way to do this in one line with, for example, slce notation?

I'm aware that it's possible to do this in one line with something like:

```
 list(map(lambda f : f[1], x))
```

But that's exactly what I described above (just using an implicit loop).

If it helps, it is safe to assume that all the elements will be indexable.

Comment: You know that even in slices there's an implicit loop :)

Comment: So **why** do you want to do this without an (implicit or explicit) loop? And how should that even be possible - the machine has to iterate over the sequence at one point or another to do this.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted to do this. It's just as I said - "is there a way". I was curious, so I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what you do, there will *always* be implicit looping somewhere.

You can also use `zip` (look ma! no loops (no `for` keyword)):

```
>>> zip(*x)[0]
(1, 4, 7)
>>> zip(*x)[1]
(2, 5, 8)
>>> zip(*x)[2]
(3, 6, 9)
```

Or list comprehensions:

```
>>> x = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
>>> l = [var[1] for var in x]
>>> l
[2, 5, 8]
```

If you wanted some other index:

```
>>> [var[0] for var in x]
[1, 4, 7]
>>> [var[2] for var in x]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: "But that's exactly what I described above (just using an implicit loop)." However, since the question has no answer which passes this constraint I'll upvote.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac: No code that works with arbitrary lists will be able to fulfill such a requirement. Quite frankly, if one of your requirements when working with lists is "should not have an implicit loop", you should think about those requirements again.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac I added a version with `zip`, dunno if its faster or anything.

Comment: It's not my requirement, it's the OP's :) I considered this question as not a real one and moved forward.

Comment: Suggesting that `zip` doesn't iterate (loop) over sequences is... wrong.

Comment: @LukasGraf Truly, but if things were up to me, I'd just use a list comprehension. There's always implicit looping, even in `map`.

Comment: That's exactly my point. So your answer should tell that to the OP, not suggest that his (rather absurd) requirement can be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [3]: x = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]

In [4]: import operator

In [5]: map(operator.itemgetter(1), x)
Out[5]: [2, 5, 8]
```

Comment: I think my `zip` version is cleverer! :D

Comment: Good for you! :) But there are two problems with the zip version: It does more work are requires more memory than is necessary if the inner lists are long, and it raises IndexError if the list is empty: `zip(*[])[1]`.

Comment: You just stole my thunder you big meany! :P Either way +1.

Answer (score 0):

To directly index your array like that, you may wish to use a numpy.array. Then you can use slice notation.